# Wi-Fi,  падение скорости соединения до 1mb/s

Tags: wifi, роутер

Доброго времени суток!

Возникла следующая проблема, объективных причин которой я найти не могу. Скажу сразу, что перед обращением сюда не один час прогуглил.

Есть точка доступа, адсл-модем с wi-fi b+g. Живу я в частном доме, модем стоит на 2-м этаже, и раздает интернет на ноут, стационарный пк, и телефон. Всё это прекрасно работает в пределах всего дома (напрямую через деревянные стены не более 30 метров) и ещё в метрах 20 вокруг дома. И горя бы я не знал, пока родителям не приспичило подключить iptv, в связи с чем, возникла необходимость перенести модем на 1-й этаж. После этого соединение с точкой работает в предела 4-6 метров, на большем расстоянии скорость соединения падает до 1mb/s, причем уровень сигнала показывает отличныйхороший, при этом модем не пингуется и интернет не раздаётся. А если отключится от точки и попробовать переподключится, ничего не получится. До ближайших соседей от точки метров 50, проверял что wi-fi работают на разных каналах. Пробовал отключать все приборы дома, которые могут создавать помехи, ничего не помогает.

Помогите, кто чем может. Спасибо!

Мои настройки точки wi-fi:

> `Access Point:ActivatedChannel:13Transmit Power:highBeacon Interval:100msRTS/CTS Threshold:2347bytesFragmentation Threshold:2346bytesDTIM:1802.11 b/g: b+gStation Number:16`
>
> `SSID Index:1PerSSID Switch:Activated`
>
> `Broadcast SSID:YesAuthentication Type:wpa2-pskEncryption:aes`

Comment: А в настройках ничего не меняли? Микроволновка есть недалеко (она перекрывает ряд каналов, а иногда и все)?

Comment: во-первых, я не знаю, что вы подразумеваете под "приборы дома, которые могут создавать помехи", я не в курсе ваших знания об излучениях, во-вторых, я задал не только этот вопрос, и в-третьих, в таком формате общения ответа вы не добьтесь!

Comment: Вместо ответа на поставленные вопросы вы дерзите, несмотря на то, что это вам нужна помощь, а не мне. Не хотите нормально и адекватно реагировать на вопросы, думайте над ответом товарища @karmadro4.

Comment: померил, показания в обе стороны одинаковые, я имею ввиду когда девайсы местами меняешь, правда ноут показывает ~-60db, телефон ~-78db, не знаю почему такая разница.

Comment: я пробовал и только b, и только g и b+g... с включенной аунтефикацией и выключенной..нифига не помогает... меня больше всего смущает что уровень сигнала отличныйхороший винда показывает, да и если достаточно быстро ноут перенести в конец дома(ну где-то секунд 15) от роутера, то соединение ещё минуту где-то держится как и должно, а потом падает и показывает вместо 54Mb/s 1 Mb/s... а уровень сигнала остается прежним.. модем в этом случае не пингуется.

Comment: да, действительно, правда что-то не нашёл где сбросить статистику и период за который она показывает, но на данный момент вот так:Tx Frames Count5334422   Rx Frames Count5386654   Tx Errors Count1627   Rx Errors Count9976770   Tx Drops Count1627   Rx Drops Count9976770

Comment: Значит что-то не так в том месте, где сейчас стоит роутер. Какие-то возникают наводки, тут надо более детально смотреть, так удаленно вряд ли кто скажет, хотя, может, где-то есть супер гуру.А что вам мешает оставить роутер на прежнем месте?

Comment: да мешает месяц назад доделанный ремонт, что бы провести сетевой кабель к приставке, просто есть ещё такой момент, что когда пролаживались коммуникации, точнее телефонный кабель к тому злополучному месту, я всё проверял на работоспособность.. и всё замечательно работало.

Answer (score 2):

1. Если вы так уверены, что это не из-за IPTV, то тут тогда либо прошивка, либо слабый канал.
2. Попробуйте перепрошить модем, если прошивка.
3. Если плохой сигнал, то можно купить роутер (например, RT-G32) и настроить его  в режиме повторителя --> в таком режиме RT-G32 расширяет покрытие существующей беспроводной сети и улучшает качество сигнала.
4. Пока больше на ум ничего не приходит :(

Answer (score 0):

IP ТВ мб забивает шлюз и валит роутер, отключите IP ТВ и сравните.

Comment: да я пробую и с отключеным айпитв и с включеным, да и даже модем не подключаю к телефонному кабелю, да и сомневаюсь что айпитв как-то на wi-fi может действовать, хотя хз.. пробовал даже провести провод от телефонной розетки где он раньше стоял, ничего не помогает. наблюдал такую ситуацию, модем стоял в злополучном месте, ноут в метре, минут 10 все работало, потом опять 1мб\с, через секунд 20 соединение поднялось, и работало ещё час, дольше не тестил. относил ноут на 5 метров через 1 стенку гипсокартонную, где-то минут 5 все работало, потом соедениение оборвалось и не поднималось. и так 2 раза)

Comment: Не думаю, что проблема в IP-TV. Только wi-fi.

Answer (score 0):

На часок отключите IP TV железку, если всё в норме, то подключайте обратно. Что именно за модем стоит? Попадались случаи в моей практике, что железка просто перегревалась и после 5-10 минут без питания оживала и радовала интернетом и телевидением. Какая прошивка стоит на модеме (заводская или может хитро-умная dd-wrt)?

Comment: ip-tv тут не причем, отключал\подключал бесполезно, модем промсвязь м200в, выданный провайдером, и прошивку никто не менял, родная стоит..

Answer (score 0):

Давайте по порядку. 1. Верните все в исходное состояние (2 этаж, без IPTV)  2. Если скорость не восстановится, то не исключены изменения в настройках роутера со стороны провайдера IPTV 3. Если ничего не поможет, попробуйте сделать полный ресет на роутере (привести все настройки к заводским). 4. Еще возможно, что некоторые компьютеры (и роутеры) в режиме энергосбережения снижают автоматически мощность излучаемого сигнала.

Comment: это все проверялось. я даже роутер поменял, теперь он умеет в 802.11n работать. так сигнал доходит но работает не стабильно, раз в минуты 3-4 соединение разрывается. и винда показывает скорость соединения 5-6 mb/s. если как и раньше роутер поставить на 2-й этаж, все отлично работает..

Answer (score 0):

попробуй уменьшить размеры пакетов и порог фрагментации, возможно он не успевает перепаковывать пакеты...

Comment: А как это сделать?